# how to smoothly trasit from higher value to lower value or vice versa in interpolation

Tags: javascript, interpolation, lerp

I have a game character which rotates in both direction.I am using interpolation to make rotation smooth a bit. Angle limit is 0 to 2PI in clockwise and 0 to -2PI in anticlockwise direction. Interpolation works well between any value between 0 to +- 2PI. Problem arises when player shifts from 2PI(6.28...) to 0.1 or 0.1 to -2PI(-6.2..) because there is a large gap between 2 values, this causes a bit jerk in rotation. How to overcome this.